# Angular Typescript component.ts not showing in index.html not sure why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, components

**shopping - list.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'shopping-list',
    template: `

    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#shoppingListItem of shoppingListItems"
        (click)="onItemClicked(shoppingListItem)"
        >{{ shoppingListItem.name }}</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="text" [{ngModel}]="selectedItem.name">
    <button (click)="onDeleteItem()">delete</button><br>
    <input type="text" #shoppingListItem>
    <button (click)="onAddItem(shoppingListItem)">Add</button>    
    `
})

export class ShoppingComponent {
    public shoppingListItems = [{ name: "milk" }, { name: "bread" }, { name: "chorizo" }, ];
    public selectedItem = { name: "" };
    onItemClicked(shoppingListItem) {
        this.selectedItem = shoppingListItem;
    }
    onAddItem(shoppingListItem) {
        this.shoppingListItems.push({ name: shoppingListItem.value });
    }
    onDeleteItem() {
        this.shoppingListItems.splice(this.shoppingListItems.indexOf(this.selectedItem), 1);
    }
}
```

**boot.ts**

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { ShoppingComponent } from "./shopping-list.component";
bootstrap(AppComponent);
bootstrap(ShoppingComponent);
```

When I do `npm start` in the windows command line it runs, but my `Shopping Component` does not show in the `index.html`. Not sure why. At the moment I'm pulling my hair trying to understand why it won't run. My `Appcomponent` works fine, it's just the `ShoppingComponent` that wont work.

Comment: `bootstrap()` is long gone. You seem to be using a quite old Angular version (pre-final) See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

Comment: Like Günther said + Without looking too closely on your code, I  immediately noticed that you are using `ngModel` with wrong syntax, instead of `[{ngModel}]`, it should be `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: thanks ya the official docs dont work with windows which is strange i was going to just try the official angular tutorial and that wont work with windows so thats why im using this github repo but guess it was built with bootstrap() and your saying that is not used now that sucks

Comment: @robert Not work with windows??? Well that's not true at all ;) It works fine with windows, there must be something else going on, if you don't get it to work.

Comment: ya on the official docs site it says fails in windows after npm start wich is strange

Comment: @robert. What exactly are you using, quickstart, webpack (??) Have you checked that you have latest npm and node versions?

Comment: got the official tutorial to work instead of npm start had to do npm build then npm run serve